# Updating a json array IN SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an array of json in a SQL Server column, I am trying to update all names to 'Joe'.

I tried the below code , but it is updating only first element of the json array

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t (I INT, JsonColumn NVARCHAR(MAX) CHECK (ISJSON(JsonColumn) > 0))

INSERT INTO #t 
VALUES (1, '[{"id":"101","name":"John"}, {"id":"102","name":"peter"}]')

INSERT INTO #t VALUES (2,'[{"id":"103","name":"dave"}, {"id":"104","name":"mark"}]')


SELECT * FROM #t

SELECT * FROM #t  
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonColumn) s

WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonColumn) s
)
UPDATE cte
SET JsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(JsonColumn, '$[' + cte.[key] + '].name', 'Joe')

SELECT * FROM #t

--  DROP TABLE #t
```

It is only updating the first element of array to joe

Current result:

[{"id":"101","name":"Joe"}, {"id":"102","name":"cd"}]

[{"id":"103","name":"Joe"}, {"id":"104","name":"mark"}]

Expected

[{"id":"101","name":"Joe"}, {"id":"102","name":"Joe"}]

[{"id":"103","name":"Joe"}, {"id":"104","name":"Joe"}]

Comment: From what I can see, you would have to update each element of the JSON array separately.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Ideally,  I want to update in one transaction

Comment: @PrasanthTP What is the structire of your JSON - fixed (`id`, `name`) or can be different? And what is your SQL Server version? Thanks.

Comment: hi json structure is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to do in one transaction, I could not think of any other ways than to create another table and store the values into new table and use for XML path with the value. Problem is you are trying to update JSON array and I am not sure how would you update the same row twice with different value. With cross apply as you have shown it creates two rows and then only you can update it to JOE.

Your query will update name = Joe for ID = 101 for first row, and Name = Joe for ID = 102 based on value column. Since these are on two different rows you are seeing only one change in your temp table.

[image]

I created one more #temp2  table to store those values and use XML path to concatenate. The final table will be #t2 table for your expected results.

```
 SELECT *
      into #t2 
    FROM #t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonColumn) s

    select *, json_value (value, '$.name') from #t2  
UPDATE #t2
SET value =  JSON_MODIFY(value, '$.name', 'Joe')  

    select t.I , 
JSONValue  = concat('[',stuff((select   ',' + value  from #t2 t1 
where t1.i = t.i 
for XML path('')),1,1,''),']')
from #t2 t 
group by t.I
```

Output:

```
I   JSONValue
1   [{"id":"101","name":"Joe"},{"id":"102","name":"Joe"}]
```

Updating original table:

```
update   t
set t.JsonColumn =t2.JSONValue
from #t t
join  (select t.I , 
JSONValue  = concat('[',stuff((select   ',' + value  from #t2 t1 
where t1.i = t.i 
for XML path('')),1,1,''),']')
from #t2 t 
group by t.I ) t2 on t.I = t2.i
```

Comment: Hi .. Thanks. It works if you have only one row in #t table. If you have more than one row it is not working as expected

Comment: I have updated the sql in the question . I am adding two rows into #t table now. You can see the result if you execute

Comment: @PrasanthTP Should your next insert have same ID ? If it is 1 I assume it should be on same row. If you insert as ID = 2, you can see it is working fine

Comment: Hi ..HOw do I update the result into original table. Like If i run SELECT * FROM #t , I want to get this result

Comment: @PrasanthTP I have added one update.. you can do in that way

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is impossible to apply more updates to one record with one command. So you need to explode JSON array to records.

You can do this with a Temporary or Variable Table and a Cursor.

```sql
-- Declare the Variable Table
DECLARE @JsonTable TABLE (
    RecordKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    ArrayIndex INT,
    ObjKey NVARCHAR(100),
    ObjValue NVARCHAR(1000)
);

-- Fill the Variable Table
INSERT INTO @JsonTable
SELECT TB1.pk as RecordKey,
    TB1data.[key] AS ArrayIndex,
    TB1dataItem.[key] as ObjKey,
    TB1dataItem.[value] as ObjValue
FROM MyTable TB1
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(TB1.data, '$.list')) TB1data
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(TB1data.value, '$')) TB1dataItem
WHERE TB1dataItem.[key] = 'name'

-- Declare Cursor and relative variables
DECLARE @recordKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @recordData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @arrayIndex INT,
    @objKey NVARCHAR(100),
    @objValue NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE JsonCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT * FROM @JsonTable;

-- Use Cursor to read any json array item
OPEN JsonCursor;
FETCH NEXT
    FROM JsonCursor
    INTO @recordKey, @arrayIndex, @objKey, @objValue;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    UPDATE TB1
    SET data = JSON_MODIFY(
        data,
        '$.list[' + CAST(@arrayIndex as VARCHAR(20)) + '].name',
        'Joe'
    )
    FROM MyTable TB1
    WHERE TB1.pk = @recordKey;

    FETCH NEXT
        FROM JsonCursor
        INTO @recordKey, @arrayIndex, @objKey, @objValue;
END;

CLOSE JsonCursor;
DEALLOCATE JsonCursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?

```
CREATE TABLE #t (
    I INT,
    JsonColumn NVARCHAR(MAX) CHECK (ISJSON(JsonColumn) > 0)
);

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES (1, '[{"id":"101","name":"John"}, {"id":"102","name":"peter"}]');

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES (2, '[{"id":"103","name":"dave"}, {"id":"104","name":"mark"}]');


SELECT CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY('{}', '$.id', j.id), '$.name', 'John'), ','), ']')
FROM #t t
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonColumn) WITH (id INT, name sysname) j
     GROUP BY t.I
```